# How to stop application before windows show UAC dialog

Tags: c#, windows, hook

I want to create basic priviledge elevation service. My design idea is admin will publish list of applications and when user tries to run one of this applications this application will run with elevated rights. I can run application from windows service context to users context as interactive

Problem is I must kill users create new process request before it shows Uac dialog to user.

As my research shows only way is to use windows hook API. I see it allows for global keyboard and mouse but I couldn't find global hook for creating new process for c#

Is this only way to achieve what I want ? 
Is it possible with c# to listen global on local system ?
Can I listen double clicks events and check if user has clicked to exe file ? Is this stupid idea ? If it's not how can I tell on which object user has double clicked ?

Comment: Which technology do you use to list the applications? Winforms? WPF? etc..?

Comment: Why down voted ? I will not list for user. There will be admin interface where he can add applications. User will not notice something as standard user he will click application and if this application is on list which admin created it will run as administrator

Comment: Yeah i understand, but what kind of interface is this? is it a small application?

Comment: Maybe this article (https://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/438006) about using a ManagementEventWatcher may help

Comment: @Leon As I understand the watcher is running as a background service. So no GUI at all.

Comment: Yes exactly. There is no interface for user. User has no idea about what happanes he just clicks and use certain apps with elevated rights. This list of apps will be created and updated from admin via some web application

Comment: Wmi management events was my first address to go :) it works but it works only after process is created. And if user is standard user before firing this event Uac dialog is displayed to user which I don't want like this.

Comment: It's something like this https://youtu.be/wtolKmu0BHs

Comment: @Cozdemir Is this something that you built already?  I'm very interested in how you achieved this.

Comment: Hi, i didn't complete that project but as far as i remember you cannot do this with wmi. You can do it with minifilter driver.Because it triggers event even before it starts to execute exe. you can catch it at that level and do as you wish. i was canceling this event (because i didn't want user to usa uac dialog ) instead of user i was executing that exe for user as my admin rights. So yeah with minifilter driver you can do it.